# Obtain full path given the folder name using RStudio

Tags: r, directory, path, rstudio

I'm working on automating a project but I've had a roadblock on this scenario.

We have multiple projects with unique project name. What I need to do is obtain the full path given the folder's name.

If the above project is located in D:\Documents then I should be able to obtain the value D:\Documents\20911 ABC DEF

Although each project is exactly the same, it will contain the same files and all, they have higher categories. Some will be under the folder Project_A, Project_B, Project_C, etc.

Or is there any way to loop through all files, looking for the specified project folder and once identified, I will obtain that path and store it in a variable?

I cannot provide a sample because I've tried searching for sources online but can't find any.

Comment: Could you not just used `getwd()`?

Comment: @Phil unfortunately, no. My RScript is saved on a working folder, separate from all the project folders. The RScript functions the same on all project files, just that they have different folder names (dependent on the project) which is why I used the folder as the user input.

Comment: I see. Could you have these projects' directories all within a directory, and then use the Project feature in RStudio to rely on its path? e.g. all in the "D://This_project/Project_A" and then create the Project feature in "D://This_project". Alternatively, the `here` package could be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `normalizePath()`, if I understand your question.

```
> setwd("~/Dropbox/9590/Lecture1")
> list.files()
 [1] "Lecture1.html"             "Lecture1.Rmd"              "Lecture1.Rproj"           
 [4] "libs"                      "syllabus_2020.aux"         "syllabus_2020.fdb_latexmk"
 [7] "syllabus_2020.fls"         "syllabus_2020.log"         "syllabus_2020.pdf"        
[10] "syllabus_2020.synctex.gz"  "syllabus_2020.tex"         "xaringan-themer.css"      
> normalizePath("Lecture1.Rproj")
[1] "/Users/david/Dropbox (DaveArmstrong)/9590/Lecture1/Lecture1.Rproj"
```

As for the looping, you could certainly do that, but what it would look like exactly  depends on your system's configuration.